# Chat-robot that will take input and response in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a small version of a chat robot that will respond to different keyword inputs in a terminal. For example, if I write `inv` it will print out its current inventory and it can look like this:

```
Item: sword
Place in inventory: 1
Item: axe
Place in inventory: 2
Item: shield
Place in inventory: 3
Item: bow
Place in inventory: 4
Item: flower
Place in inventory: 5
```

And that part I have solved. The problem occurs when I'm going to give an input like `inv pick hammer` or `inv drop hammer`. Now I have to handle somehow that the same start keyword can occur in multiple cases.

I have created some kind of handler that takes a argument (the input from user) and splits it into a list. Looks something like this:

```
def splitIntoWords(argOne):
"""
Function that splits list into words
"""
#list to keep and split up the user input
inputList = []
inputList = argOne.split()
#print(str(inputList) + "splitIntoWords")
#term we want to search for
term = "citat"
quitOne = "q"
replyHej = "hej"
replyLunch = "lunch"
inventory = "inv"
invPick = "pick"

#invDrop = "drop"
lenght = len(inputList)
nextWord = inputList[lenght-1]



if term in inputList:
    return term
elif quitOne in inputList:
    return quitOne
elif replyHej in inputList:
    return replyHej
elif replyLunch in inputList:
    return replyLunch
elif inventory in inputList:
    if invPick in inputList:
        return ("q")
    else:
        return inventory
else:
    return result
```

As you can see I have started to do and if inside an elif and tried to do multiple checks on the same list, but it doesn't work for me.
Is there any other way I can do check to see it that more than one keyword appears in the list?

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper, thanks for editing my post

Comment: No problem :) @anderssinho

Comment: How about determing the size of the splitted array, if the user entered 3 words and the first word was "inv" you then go and check the next one etc.

Comment: @DZDomi, so instead of 
elif inventory in inputList:
    if invPick in inputList:

you mean I should try something like:

elif inventory in inputList:
    if len(inputlist) == 3

Or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted and tested the code and it works.

```
def splitIntoWords( argOne):

    result = "hej"
    """
    Function that splits list into words
    """
    # list to keep and split up the user input
    inputList = []
    inputList = argOne.split()
    print(str(inputList) + "splitIntoWords")
    # term we want to search for
    term = "citat"
    quitOne = "q"
    replyHej = "hej"
    replyLunch = "lunch"
    inventory = "inv"
    invPick = "pick"

    # invDrop = "drop"
    lenght = len(inputList)
    nextWord = inputList[lenght - 1]

    if term in inputList:
        return term
    elif quitOne in inputList:
        return quitOne
    elif replyHej in inputList:
        return replyHej
    elif replyLunch in inputList:
        return replyLunch
    elif inventory in inputList:
        if invPick in inputList:
            return ("q")
        else:
            return inventory
    else:
        return result

print splitIntoWords("inv pick sword")
```

Test

```
python inventory.py 
['inv', 'pick', 'sword']splitIntoWords
q
```

The `q` above is the expected result.

Comment: Okay then I must have done something else wrong. Thanks